# How to change the dependency of weblogic server when at runtime it referes to another jar?

Tags: dependencies, weblogic12c, jackson-databind

I am trying to run my application on weblogic server.
I have specified the required jars in the required versions in the pom file of my application.
At run time the server is referencing the jar from
`$Middleware_Home/oracle_common/modules` which has an older version of the jar.
How do i update the version in this folder? or make the server refer to the version specified in my pom file.

Answer (score 0):

In your weblogic-application.xml file, you can add the `<prefer-application-packages>` element. It would like the below.

```
<weblogic-application
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.0/weblogic-application.xsd">

  <classloader-structure>
    <module-ref>
      <module-uri>appname.war</module-uri>
    </module-ref>
  </classloader-structure>
  
  <session-descriptor>
    <cookie-path>/appname</cookie-path>
  </session-descriptor>

  <prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>org.apache.logging.log4j.* </package-name>
  </prefer-application-packages>
</weblogic-application>
```

Alternatively, You can use the prefer-web-inf-classes element in your weblogic.xml file and set it to true. Please note that you if use this, the prefer-application-packages will be ignored. More about it [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP660)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
                        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
                        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.9/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

  <wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
  </wls:container-descriptor>
  <wls:context-root>appname</wls:context-root>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```